# Model not posted to controller using Ajax BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I am confused and would really like some help. I am a first timer so would ask you to be patient with me. So here goes.
I am trying to post the model to the controller using Ajax Begin Form.But I always get null at the controller.
This View

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="secondColumn">
 <div id="OtherData">
  @Html.Partial("BindOthLangData", Model.VodCombinedData[2])
 </div>
 </div>
```

partial view BindOthLangData

```
@model Domain.Model.Combinedmodel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("selectAction", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions {       LoadingElementId = "loaderdiv" }))
{
for (var i = 0; i < Model.ContentDataLst.Count; i++)
{
      <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="section">
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ContentDataLst[i].OperatorFiledName)
               @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ContentDataLst[i].AttributeID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ContentDataLst[i].Srid)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ContentDataLst[i].Value)
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContentDataLst[i], Model.ContentDataLst[i].OperatorFiledName, new { @class = "field-label text-left" })
                <label class="field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ContentDataLst[i],  Model.ContentDataLst[i].HtmlType)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
<div class="col-md-12 mt15 text-right" id="reject">
    <button id="scms" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save">Save CMS Metadata </button>
</div>
}
```

This is the Action

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult selectAction(String submitButton,Combinedmodel objData)
    {
        String status = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            status = saveData(objData);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            status = "Error Occurred";
        }
        return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And this is my model

```
public class Combinedmodel
{
   List<Data> contentDataLst = new List<Data> ();

    public List<Data> ContentDataLst
    {
        get { return contentDataLst; }
        set { contentDataLst = value; }
    }
}

public class Data
{
  public string OperatorFiledName {get;set;}
  public int AttributeID {get;set;}
  public int Srid {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
  public string HtmlType {get;set;}
}
```

I do not know what is that i am doing wrong.. Please help. The Action is called but the model that is posted to the controller is null.

Comment: Can you use the browser developer tools and in the Network tab confirm that you are sending the data to the server?

Comment: Remove `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ContentDataLst[i],  Model.ContentDataLst[i].HtmlType)` (unless you have a custom `EditorTemplate` for type of `Data` then its generating `name="ContentDataLst[0]` which wipes out all the other data. Everything else in the code you have shown is correct but you have not shown enough information to understand what your trying to do with that `EditorFor()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I am trying to generate controls dynamically and that is why i am using EditorFor with EditorTemplates, the first parameters is the data that i want to bind to the template and the second parameter provides the name of the template.

Comment: You have not even shown the code associated with it!. Just comment it out and check that the model now binds to the hidden input properties.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I commented the EditorFor just as you suggested and it did not work. The values were still not posted to the controller

Comment: The rest of your code is fine. If its not binding, then there is something else you have not shown us causing the problem.

Comment: @stephenMuecke there is nothing else, this is it :(

Comment: Refer [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XABBgg) to prove its not `null`

Comment: @stephenMuecke  Thank you for the fiddle, I am using Ajax begin form and your example had a html beginform , do you think that makes a difference.. I am absolutely confused as to where i am going wrong

Comment: Does not make any difference (and `Ajax.BeginForm()` is awful and not even supported in the latest MVC. You should learn to use `jQuery.ajax()` and its shortcuts).

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok then i will try using Jquery.ajax() in that case will a Serializearray() function do to get all the data bound to this partial view only ????

Comment: You use `$('form').serialize()` (not `serializeArray'`) but it makes no difference whether you use  normal form submit or ajax. The code you have shown works and the model is not `null`. Its something you have not shown causing the problem. And what do you mean  _partial view_?

Comment: The view that i have added in the question is a partial view and i want to post only the data which was bound to this sepcific parial view

Comment: So you do have other code (not _there is nothing else, this is it_)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited my question i have added how i add the partial view to my main view

Comment: Assuming you do not have any other forms in your main view that would result in nested forms, what you have shown will work fine (the model will not be `null`)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the for-loop, you are posting `List<Data>`, not `Combinedmodel`.

Update your action method parameter to:

```
public JsonResult selectAction(String submitButton, List<Data> contentDataLst)
```

Comment: The model in the view is `Combinedmodel` and the code is creating inputs based on properties of the model so the POST method must be `Combinedmodel objData`